# Easiest way to present design on Device (imac/macbook/iphone) screen?

Tags: presentation-design

I see so many people presenting their designs/portfolio on device screens, like a macbook pro or imac or even iphone. I'm also seeing program developers and others do so who I presume aren't specifically talented in graphic design, so I was wondering if anyone knows of a website/template people are using? I'm sure it wouldn't be that difficult to do from scratch, but if such a template exists it would be helpful.

Examples:

[image]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2alM.png]

Comment: I'm confused by the question...you want to design your portfolio web site so that your work appears on a fake screen in the web browser? I guess you could do that with any image of the device you want to show...though I don't know if I see the point to it all.

Comment: You can show your portfolio image's here just slice image's and place them according to the screen of mac

Answer (score 1):

These are simply multiple images combined in a raster editing application such as Photoshop.

You simply place an image of your web site or app, or whatever on a layer above a photo of the computer, then save the entire thing as one, single image.

[image: layers]
(Screenshot of Photoshop CS5.1 with layers Panel)

There's no super-secret dynamic web code which does this. It's merely saving images so they ***look*** like they are on a screen.

If you are proficient enough with CSS you could use a background image for the computer, then have additional image overlay the computer in the HTML/CSS. But generally it's just single images.

Answer (score -1):

Check this link out - free vector template: http://www.pixeden.com/psd-mock-up-templates/imac-psd-mockup-template

Comment: Hi tim, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer! Can you add a bit of info about what we can find at the link you provide? That way, your answer might still be of value in case the link breaks at a later time. Link breaking is why we're not keen on link-only answers here. Don't be discouraged, we're happy to have you! Thanks again and enjoy the site.